# VBScript SendKeys 800A0408 Invalid Character

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys, invalid-characters

I'm getting this compilation error with a script I was working on using WScript.SendKeys.  Yes, I have saved the .vbs file to be encoded as ANSI.  It says the error is on Line 48, which is this:

```
shell.SendKeys {ENTER}
```

The rest of the script works just fine if I take this line out, in case that's important.

Comment: SendKeys wants a String argument use shell.SendKeys "{ENTER}". { and } are invalid characters that's what the error is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enclose `{ENTER}` in quotes. `SendKeys` expects a string parameter.

```
shell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks!  I probably looked over that since I used a variable with sendkeys one line previously.

Comment: @GenericName ==> In this case you must accept this answer ! So take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/tour